# VBA - Office 365 x64 bit - Completely crashing

Tags: vba, ms-office

This is my first time asking for any help on stack overflow, let alone commenting so please be gentle with me :)

I am at a loss with this one, I will give as much information as possible.

***Issue***

I would like to preface, this code does not cause any crashes on the latest update of 0365, only on Version 1807 & earlier. It also does not crash on the 32 bit version at all which makes me think it's a 64 bit issue. My client cannot update from this version either so simply asking them to update is not going to be able to happen.

I have narrowed the crashing down to this particular section.

```
Public Function GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL As Long) As String
'*******************************************************************************
'*  Function:     GetSpecialFolder
'*  Purpose:      Wraps the apis to retrieve folders such as My Docs etc.

'*******************************************************************************
      Dim idlstr                   As Long
      Dim sPath                         As String
      Dim IDL                           As ITEMIDLIST
      Const MAX_LENGTH = 260

      'Fill the IDL structure with the specified folder item.
      On Error GoTo GetSpecialFolder_Error

      idlstr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation _
          (0, CSIDL, IDL)

      If idlstr = 0 Then
        'Get the path from the IDL list, and return the folder adding final "\".
        sPath = Space$(MAX_LENGTH)
        **idlstr = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal IDL.mkid.cb, ByVal sPath)**
        If idlstr Then
          GetSpecialFolder = Left$(sPath, InStr(sPath, Chr$(0)) _
              - 1) & "\"
        End If
      End If

    procExit:
      On Error Resume Next
      Exit Function

    GetSpecialFolder_Error:
      CommonErrorHandler lngErrNum:=Err.Number, strErrDesc:=Err.Description, _
        strProc:="GetSpecialFolder", strModule:="modWinAPI", lngLineNum:=Erl
      Resume procExit

    End Function
```

And here is the declaration

```
'File system
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, pidl As ITEMIDLIST) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr

Private Type ITEMIDLIST
mkid                              As ShortItemId
End Type

Private Type ShortItemId
  cb                                As Long
  abID                              As Byte
End Type
```

I have tried adding Long**Ptr** as suggested in documents I've found online but it hasn't helped.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` does not fill in the memory you allocate for `ITEMIDLIST` like `Declare`d function usually do, it allocates a new piece of memory that you are later [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation#parameters) to free with `CoTaskMemFree`. That makes it pointless to declare `ITEMIDLIST` as a structure in VBA to begin with (and your declaration is wrong anyway, `cb` must be `Integer`, and `abID` is a variable-length byte array, not a single byte).

If you needed to do something with individual members of a structure allocated in this way, you would have to copy them out of the returned pointer with `CopyMemory`. Luckily, you don't need to do any of that because `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` returns a pointer to `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE`, and `SHGetPathFromIDList` [accepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlista#parameters) `PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE`:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As LongPtr, ByVal nFolder As Long, ByRef pIdl As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pIdl As LongPtr, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32.dll" (pv As Any)
```

```
Public Function GetSpecialFolder(ByVal CSIDL As Long) As String
  Dim retval As Long
  Dim pIdl As LongPtr
  Dim sPath As String

  Const MAX_LENGTH = 260


  retval = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL, pIdl)

  If retval = 0 Then
    sPath = Space$(MAX_LENGTH)
    retval = SHGetPathFromIDList(pIdl, sPath)

    If retval <> 0 Then
      GetSpecialFolder = Left$(sPath, InStr(sPath, Chr$(0)) - 1) & "\"
    End If

    CoTaskMemFree ByVal pIdl
  End If

End Function
```

Note that it's pointless to have an `On Error Goto` in such function because Windows API generally do not raise exceptions, they return error codes. It *would* make sense if you used `Err.Raise ...` after finding out a return value indicates an error.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. +1.  `SHGetPathFromIDList` returns a bool though.

Comment: @Comintern `Len(bool)` is 2 in VBA, so like with `hWnd`, I'm keen on keeping the size correct ;)

Comment: Fair enough - I personally let the marshaller handle that so I can retain the VBA semantics.

Comment: @Comintern You got me wondering about that marshalling, so I've done a little test and nope, it truncates without actually marshalling. If you declare the function and the `retval` variable `As Boolean`, the bits that end up in the `retval` variable on VBA side are `0x0001`, which is "truthy", but does not actually equal `True`. They would be `0xFFFF` if there was actually marshalling. Which means that doing `retval_bool = SHGetPathFromIDList(pIdl, sPath)` and then `If retval_bool Then` *will* execute the `If`, but `If retval_bool = True Then` *will not*. (I have tested, it does not `= True`).

Comment: Interesting - I'd assumed that the cast would have been performed before the return value reached the call site. That said, in terms of pure efficiency, using the raw return value is probably better (avoids the cast).  I guess this is a rare instance where I actually prefer the implicit cast.

Comment: Hi guys - I had it working on my laptop but trying to edit the main file now, for some reason I'm getting a ByRef mismatch error for pIdl in this code now?

Comment: @RCW05 You cannot be getting a ByRef mismatch for `pIdl` with this code. Is it actually the code you are running?

Comment: This exact code when copy and pasted causes ByRef Argument type mismatch, tried it again this morning to be sure!

Comment: @RCW05 On which line exactly?

Comment: retval = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL, pIdl) - specifically the pIdl bit at the end. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but can't get it to work :(

Comment: @RCW05 Apparently you have a conflicting version of SHGetSpecialFolderLocation `Declare`d somewhere else. What does [the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAlL.png) say about its parameters?

Comment: We have this also declared in an else statement for the 32 bit but I haven't updated that code yet, could this be the issue?

Comment: @RCW05 Yes, and you should not have different `Declare`s for 32 and 64 bits. That is why there is `LongPtr` to begin with. The only reason to have two declarations would be if you still support Office 2003 and below where you don't have `PtrSafe` and `LongPtr`, but then you need to branch on `#If VBA7 Then`, not on `#If Win64 Then`.

Comment: Understood. Just FYI I have this working like a charm now, Thank you so much - would buy you both a coffee if I could!

Answer (score 1):

TBH, I have no clue how this was functioning correctly on a 32 bit build.  The declarations for the two structures are incorrect.  This one...

> ```
> Private Type ShortItemId
>   cb                                As Long
>   abID                              As Byte
> End Type
> ```

...is defined in [the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shtypes/ns-shtypes-_shitemid) as this:

> ```
> typedef struct _SHITEMID {
>   USHORT cb;
>   BYTE   abID[1];
> } SHITEMID;
> ```

Note that `abID` is an array, and `cb` is an unsigned short (you can use an `Integer` for that in VBA, but it definitely is not a `Long`).

In addition, this structure (wrapped in the [ITEMIDLIST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shtypes/ns-shtypes-_itemidlist)) is ***not even supposed to be allocated by the caller***, but must be *freed* by the caller:

> It is the responsibility of the calling application to free the returned IDList by using CoTaskMemFree.

Re the pointers, the only pointers (that aren't being marshaled from `String`) are the 
`pidl` parameter of [`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation) and the pointer to `ppidl` in [`SHGetPathFromIDList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetpathfromidlista).  Note that you *can't* use a VBA defined struct, because you need to free the memory when you're done.  Something like this will work:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetSpecialFolderLocation Lib "shell32.dll" _
    (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal nFolder As Long, pidl As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
    Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As LongPtr, ByVal pszPath As String) As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal pv As LongPtr)

Private Const S_OK As Long = 0
Private Const MAX_LENGTH = 260

Public Function GetSpecialFolder(ByVal CSIDL As Integer) As String
    Dim result As Long
    Dim path As String
    Dim idl_ptr As LongPtr

    'Fill the IDL structure with the specified folder item.
    result = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL, idl_ptr)

    If result = S_OK Then
        'Get the path from the IDL list, and return the folder adding final "\".
        path = Space$(MAX_LENGTH)
        If SHGetPathFromIDList(idl_ptr, path) Then
            GetSpecialFolder = Left$(path, InStr(path, vbNullChar) - 1) & "\"
        End If
        CoTaskMemFree idl_ptr
    End If
End Function
```

Note that per the discussion in the comments, you could technically declare `hwndOwner` as `LongPtr` as well, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: When trying this I'm getting an idl_ptr ByRef argument type Mismatch.. any idea why?

Comment: @RCW05 That's odd, works just fine for me. Which line gives you the error? Note that `pidl As LongPtr` is *not* declared `ByVal`, so it's implicitly `ByRef` in the declaration.

Comment: @RCW05 - Ahhh... I changed the function signature to `CSIDL As Integer` because, well, CSIDL is not a `Long`. Make that explicitly `ByVal` (see the edit).

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Even this code is now giving me ByRef argument type mismatch when copy and pasted?

Comment: Please ignore this sorry - I had another version declared and didn't realise it would conflict .... DOH!

Comment: @RCW05 - NP, glad you got it sorted.